# Detect movement in a very power efficient way

Tags: low-power, wifi, accelerometer, esp8266, movement

I am working on a device i can strap on to an expensive electronics instrument, and when someone moves the instrument, the device detects it and sends its position from a GPS to a server, via WiFi, where people can do a look-up on the instruments last known location.

The device will need to run on a battery, so the whole setup needs to be as power efficient as possible.

The WiFi chip i am using is the ESP8266. Not a big surprise, i know, but it has a decent range, doesn't consume much power in sleep mode (around 20uA if memory serves me right) and is cheap as wood.

Next challenge. I need a way to detect movement in a "as low power as possible" way, so i went digging, and found a couple of ways. There is a kind of switches that can detect movement, either by rolling a ball to make contact or by moving a spring to make contact ([Spring switch](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1766)), but i want it to be omni directional, so no "rolling ball switch", and i want it to be sensitive enough to detect when the instrument is moved, and i haven't been able to find a "spring switch" with enough sensitivity.

There is also the possibility to use an accelerometer to detect movement, but that consumes a lot of power. At least, that's what i believe.

But! I found an accelerometer which i think gives a power saving way to wake the ESP8266 when movement is detected.
The accelerometer is a MMA7660FC, made by NXP ([Datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MMA7660FC.pdf)). In the datasheet on page 13, under "Auto-Wake/Sleep", i interpret what they write as the accelerometer can sleep until a directional change is detected and provide an interrupt signal, which i can use to wake up the ESP8266!

So, here comes the two questions i have:

1. Is what i am saying about the MMA7660FC true? Its not the ideal solution because of the current it will draw, even if it is sleeping, but it is better having to change the battery a little more than having a failed project.
2. Is there a way to detect movement that i have missed and is useful for my application?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: *but i want it to be uni directional* That can be done with these switches as well, just use 3 for X,Y and Z direction. I once build a prototype like this just for fun and indeed it detects almost any movement. There are also spring (coil) based switches which detect acceleration. These are used in automatic bicycle lights.

Comment: Hmm, never thought about it that way. If one could buy a "rolling ball switch" with all three axis included, that would be really useful in this situation. But i am trying to keep the footprint to a minimum as well, so if i can do it without three ball switches, that would be best. I did try with the spring based switch, as i wrote, but the ones i could find wasn't sensitive enough, so i left that idea again.

Comment: You did say "its position from a GPS". So, wake up periodically (say, every hour, or vary according to your power budget and needs) and check the GPS position. If it's different, it's moved.

Comment: I have never seen one of those 3-axis in one. But there's no need, just use 3 switches and mount them in different orientations, that's what I did.

Comment: Personally I think the GPS position might give issues as GPS by itself is not that accurate to reliably detect movement of a few meters or tens of meters. Also, accurate positioning with GPS requires the GPS to be on for some time and that eats batteries. Besides that it is often so that GPS reception inside a building is very bad and unreliable.

Comment: The thing is, if i do it that way, and someone moves the instrument down in a celler with no way to get signal from a GPS satelite, im screwed. There is a bigger chance to know where it is if i can detect movement and log position every minute or so, and if not moved, only wake up every one week or so. And by the way, it is not meant as a way to stop thieves, it is purely to know the location of an instrument that is in range of our WiFi.

Comment: How about a rolling ball switch and a 100dB alarm with key pad code for arm/disarm. (much cheaper).  nah, how about its moving overseas and battery wears out

Comment: I like your way of thinking, Tony, but not suitable this time ;) Bimpel, the GPS i have actually has a good reception, even inside, so i dont think that will be an issue, and it supports sleep mode, and wakes up in about 15-20 seconds, its pretty solid.

Comment: it needs better specs for event input signal and noise

Comment: What do you mean, Tony? That it's not fast enough to aqcuire a signal to be used when event driven?

Comment: In that case, (no GPS in the cellar) what use is the position it reports to the server?

Comment: You could use a ST LIS2DE12 motion sensor. It can be configured to generate an interrupt on movement larger than a configurable threshold. It consumes a couple of uA.

Comment: The usefulness comes because it will be reporting with little time in between, and thus I can see where it went missing, and guess my way from that. Again, not used to prevent theft, I just work at a very big place where instruments get scattered all the time

Comment: That sound awesome, Peter, I will look into that, thanks!

Comment: Low cost Doppler RADAR modules consume 10's of uA (from memory).

Comment: "Uni directional"= one direction.  "Omni directional"= all directions.

Comment: Woops, thats me in a nutshell, now corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your assumption about the MMA7660FC is correct. It can generate an interrupt for your controller in its "Active Mode". In this configuration the device draws 47 μA.
2. A better solution would be using this 3-axis accelerometer from ST [LIS3DH](http://www.st.com/en/mems-and-sensors/lis3dh.html). It does exactly the same thing, but using 2 μA instead.

I would say this is the most low-power solution for what you are describing. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for. It really is hard to find a suitable component, no central place to look it up, so i really appreciate it!

Comment: @Fiskelord I frequently use www.digikey.com to look up parts in scenarios where I don't know where to start.

Comment: @Fiskelord would you be able to share your solution with LIS3DH? I am looking to build something similar and would love to use your solution.

Comment: @rams I would love to, but the project is intellectual property of the place i work at, so i would get in trouble if anyone finds out that i shared the project. I can say, however, that the LIS3DH works terrific when used like this. Easy to recommend

Comment: @Fiskelord I understand. Just wanted to know how LIS3DH interrupt was being used to reset the ESP without going into endless reset cycles when LIS is in motion. Any chance you would be able to share clues about that part?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but a reaction to your statement:

> i want it to be omni directional, so no "rolling ball switch"

This makes no sense.  Rolling ball switches are omni-directional.  Their orientation doesn't matter.  When their orientation changes or they are jarred, the state of the switch will change.

The switch state change can be used to wake up a microcontroller.  Or, the micro can wake up periodically, turn on the pullup for the switch, test the switch, then go back to sleep if there is no change.  Waking up every 50 ms or so for a few µs at a time is still very low average current draw.